Do revolutions invariably lead to more chaos and suffering?
It is a common perception that revolutions lead to increased chaos and suffering. However, are there instances where a revolution has resulted in immediate benefits for the people of a nation (many revolutions ended in benefit of the people but after many years of chaos  I am asking for revolutions that didn't lead to more chaos afterwards )? Specifically, are there historical examples where the aftermath of a revolution did not plunge the country into greater disarray but instead improved the conditions and quality of life for its citizens?

Since the term ‘immediate benefits’ is seen to be ambiguous, my definition of that is: if a revolution started for certain reasons and, after the revolution succeeded in overthrowing the old regime, all of the problems that angered the people were solved after the new government came in.
What I mean by ‘increased chaos and suffering’ is: even after the revolution took down the old regime, all of the problems that caused the revolution to start with were not solved and even became worse.

I'm sure that the U.S. citizens will no doubt claim that their revolution improved life in everyway. The main problem that revolutions have is that the main (often only) thing uniting the revolutionaries is their hatred of the old regime. Once victory is achieved the divisions appear as different parties have different goals.

Greater disarray at the state level and improved quality of life for citizens are not mutually exclusive. See e.g. 1989 in East Germany.

Precise definitions of what's a "revolution" and what's a "benefit" could help this question. Almost by definition, a true revolution is a chaotic process, and is too simple to talk about "the country" and its citizens as whole because revolutionary social and political change will generally have winners and losers of different kinds at different levels of society.

This question I believe seriously underplays the amount of chaos and suffering that often occurs prior to revolutions, particularly in countries where those in power feel no need to be bound by rule-of-law (which is the cause of many revolutions)

@T.E.D. I am not trying to "underplays the amount of chaos and suffering that often occurs prior to revolutions" but I am asking for examples where the  revolution did solve the problems of the people, there are many revolution (especially in the Arab world) where they succeeded on taking down the old regime but things got worse like Libya for example (see my last edit).

@BrianZ I edited the question, I hope it is clear now.

@mathematicsenjoyer I didn't vote to close but based on your edit I would say the question is trivial... No, there has never been a revolution that solved "all of the problems" that motivated the revolutionaries. Most revolutions partially solved some of the problems, and worsened or caused other problems at the same time.

The Portuguese Carnation Revolution of 1974 almost certainly contradicts that this is "invariable" since it did not lead to more chaos and suffering.
The revolution started as a military coup to overthrow the authoritarian Estado Novo government, but there was no actual military action or violence used. The revolution lasted six hours from the radio broadcast that signalled its start to the resignation of the government. That time was largely characterized by peaceful mass protests on the street, which ceased when the government surrendered. A total of four people died after being shot by government soldiers (the soldiers were later prosecuted).
The revolution restored democracy in Portugal and ended the Portuguese Colonial War, and produced major social, economic, territorial, demographic, and political changes in Portugal.

This question is very difficult to answer because of the conditions that typically usher in a revolution tend to be very poor in the first place. After the revolution is "done" (and it's not always easy to draw that line - did the Russian Revolution end in 1917 or 1922 or 1991?) the economy does not immediately improve; the new regime inherits the disarray of the old one compounded with the cost of the revolution itself. Even the American Revolution had to deal with armed uprisings against unpopular policies such as "the country needs money to operate."
In other words, a revolution doesn't remove the problem; it just puts new people in charge of doing something about it. Turning the arrow on the graph from a downward trend to an upward trend takes time.
For example, consider Romania. The revolution came after nearly a decade of crippling austerity - and for the first two years the economy continued to plunge. The new government's liberalization led to an intensification of poverty and unemployment for the following decade. This is a universal feature of post-Soviet economies; it's hard to say whether austerity under socialism vs austerity under capitalism would have achieved different outcomes.
Of course, the new order can prioritize some benefits over others. After the Russian Revolution, infant mortality dropped and literacy skyrocketed, parallel with mass suffering and death due to the inhumane expropriation of livelihoods, especially from Ukrainian and Kazakh peasants. Similarly, the Haitian Revolution devastated the economy - but it was an extractive slave-based economy, where the benefits were entirely in the service of a tiny upper class.
There might be one exception I could find - as outlined in this answer, Cuba's revolution was able to avoid many of the problems faced by other revolutions.

This answer very much focuses on economic aspects, but there are examples where revolutions brought immediate and measurable benefits in other areas. Such as freedom to travel for East Germans in 1989.

I would push back on that - if the "immediate benefit to the people of a nation" is the ability to go to a different nation that doesn't have any of the problems of the first one, does it really count?

Being able to visit relatives or travel to all the cool places in Europe is definitely a big benefit.


immediate benefits for the people

Like that short fragment of a sentence carries so much ambiguity that you almost have to define every word or word group of it.
Also the perspective of chaos, disarray, suffering and worsening conditions is that of an outsider looking on a country and seeing all these groups as being one collective whole. But that's most likely not the perspective of the groups revolting against each other, as some sort of disconnect between them is either the reason or the manifestation of their conflict.
And so if the wealth of that country decreases because the proponents of the old regime lose while the victorious revolutionaries gain ever so slightly, then they might still consider that a win, despite a neutral observer seeing a decrease in idk their GDP or whatnot.
So what is "for the people" and who are "the people" might be pretty ambiguous and how it's defined may matter crucially.
Next would be what "benefits" are. Like do you only count increases in wealth, health, standards of living or more general material improvements. Or do you also count political participation, free speech, freedom of assembly, freedom of movement, cultural freedom etc so immaterial goods?
Like for the latter part it's possible to achieve immediate improvement upon the radical change of the structure of a regime. In terms of the material improvements, well that's difficult. Unless the dictator was hoarding loads of wealth that can be used to improve stuff and hasn't found a "benevolent" country granting him and more importantly his assets refuge or used them to crush the revolution or burned them just for the sake of it, then you'll be in the same shitty position just with a different system. Again immaterial improvement but materially change usually doesn't happen immediately.
Another scenario where a revolution could result in a windfall situation might have been cold war drama, so if your revolution falls in line with the interests of a global super power they might show massive structural support to your new system in order to make sure that the other global superpower(s) isn't. So you might end up with immediate improvement, though in the worst case scenario the continued struggle of the superpowers is not manifesting by supporting you materially, but by fighting proxy wars on your soil and making things even worse. So kind of a gamble.
Though a comparable situation might be a new democracy joining international organizations and getting money and support to get them started which they previously wouldn't have gotten due to people not being fond of their dictator.
Though those kinda depend on external factors that are outside of the control of the revolutionaries.
Also with regards to revolutions one is often tempted to think of the big violent revolutions, revolutionary wars and civil wars. And yeah it's hard to come out with a net positive when you're killing each other and burning your countries wealth unless you discount the loses of the other side as "the enemy".
But revolution technically is just a massive structural change in a short period of time. So while that usually is the result of postponed and/or suppressed reform that bursts out violently. It could also happen peacefully.
If you have enough of a large union of different groups, adding up to a majority, maybe even already worked out and tested parallel institutions and whatnot and maybe already sought diplomatic relations with others and so on. A revolution can also be quite boring and overwhelmingly non-violent. Now again the immediate improvement can mostly only occur from outside contribution, redistribution of unused wealth or immaterial gains.
Such things might include de-colonization, peaceful transitions of power from monarchies or dictatorships to a democracy, constitutional assemblies and foundations of a nation state and so on.
Now massive, immediate change, is almost by definition chaotic, but that isn't necessarily a bad thing if what you revolted against was a stagnant oppressive order for example.
